# htaccess rewrite tweaking

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a reqrite rule that is almost doing what I want. I would appreciate some info on how to tweak it.

```
RewriteRule ^gallery(/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?)?)?$ gallery.php?groupId=$3 [NC,QSA]
```

this rule works but I need it to handle one more argument like this

```
RewriteRule ^gallery(/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?)?)?$ gallery.php?groupId=$3**&showpage=$6** [NC,QSA]
```

I need the rule to handle

```
gallery
gallery/
gallery/somegroupid
gallery/somegroupid/
gallery/somegroupid/2
gallery/somegroupid/2/
```

I appreciate the input.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in ore rule:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery(/((([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/(\d+))?)/?)?)?$ gallery.php?groupId=$4&showpage=$6 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: this is working but its throwing a 404 if i specify a showpage. it works fine for /gallery/pagegroup but if i specify a show page such as /gallery/pagegroup/2 then i get a 404, any ideas.

Comment: what happens when you put <beginning of your URLs here>/gallery.php?groupid=pagegroup&showpage=2 directly in your browser?

Comment: it works fine and as expected and shows page 2 of that groups photos. just checked it this minute. thanks for this help I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks a million for this. I figured out the problem. I had placed the rule below the rewrite condition for the catchall rule in my htaccess and that was screwing with stuff. this worked a treat thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have essentially the same configuration as you on one of my sites.

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery.php?groupId=$1&showpage=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ gallery.php?groupId=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```